# How to make figcaption go directly under an image when float:left

Tags: html, css

I have an image as a hyperlink, and have used float:left. When I try to use a figcaption, it doesn't position where I want. Instead it shows the figcaption at the top to the right of the image!

Here is my html

```
<figure>
                <a href = "https://www.google.com"><img src = "asdasd.jpg"></a>
                <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
            </figure>
```

Here is my CSS

```
img{
            float:left;
            margin: 15px;
        }
```

Comment: remove the float then OR clear float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the float of the image on the figcaption

```
figcaption {
  clear: both;
}
```